# Convert lists from separate variables into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have 5 separate lists from different variable as below. How can I convert them to a pandas dataframe.

```
a = [1.4, 1.3]
b = [0.8, 0.8]
c = [2.4, 1.6]
d = [3.6, 2.9]
e = [2.8, 2.5]
```

Expected dataframe

```
x,y
1.4, 1.3
0.8, 0.8
2.4, 1.6
3.6, 2.9
2.8, 2.5
```

Comment: This question needs more details, are these lists in seperate variables or a list of lists?

Comment: @ Erfan. These are lists in different variables

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.DataFrame to convert your list to a df:

```
ls = [[1.4, 1.3],
      [0.8, 0.8],
      [2.4, 1.6],
      [3.6, 2.9],
      [2.8, 2.5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(ls,columns=['x','y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
import pandas as pd

df = [[1.4, 1.3],
      [0.8, 0.8],
      [2.4, 1.6],
      [3.6, 2.9],
      [2.8, 2.5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['x', 'y']).to_string(index=False)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   x    y
 1.4  1.3
 0.8  0.8
 2.4  1.6
 3.6  2.9
 2.8  2.5
```