# How to generate a dataframe from lists of separate variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have asked the same question here: [Convert lists from separate variables into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64723083/convert-lists-from-separate-variables-into-a-dataframe) which was closed.

The suggestions provided do not answer my question because what I have is not a list of lists but lists from separate variable as below.

```
a=[1.4, 1.3]
b=[0.8, 0.8]
c=[2.4, 1.6]
d=[3.6, 2.9]
e=[2.8, 2.5]
```

How can I convert the above separate lists to a pandas dataframe to get the below output

```
column_1,column_2
1.4, 1.3
0.8, 0.8
2.4, 1.6
3.6, 2.9
2.8, 2.5
```

**[CORRECTION]**

Actually the lists that I provided above is not individual lists as previously mentioned, but rather the output of 2 functions, mean_function() and stddev_function(), which I put in a list as below:

`feat = [mean_function(), stddev_function()]`, and the output of feat gives the lists:

```
[1.4, 1.3]
[0.8, 0.8]
[2.4, 1.6]
[3.6, 2.9]
[2.8, 2.5]
```

So what I need is to first convert the sequence of lists (from variable ***feat***) to individuals lists as below and then convert to a dataframe:

```
a=[1.4, 1.3]
b=[0.8, 0.8]
c=[2.4, 1.6]
d=[3.6, 2.9]
e=[2.8, 2.5]
```

Sorry for the inaccurate details in the beginning.

Comment: do you want a data.frame or a csv file?

Comment: @StuoidWolf. If I can have a dataframe then I can easily write it to a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer does answer the question, but it takes one extra step of putting variables into a list:

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [1.4, 1.3]
b = [0.8, 0.8]
c = [2.4, 1.6]
d = [3.6, 2.9]
e = [2.8, 2.5]

L = [a, b, c, d, e]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=["one", "two"])
print(df)
```

---

**Updated** after question was updated.

The syntax of:

```py
feat = [mean_function(), stddev_function()]
```

suggests that `feat` should be a list (regardless of what `mean_function()` and `stddev_function()` do).

So the output should look something like:

```py
[[1.4, 1.3]
 [0.8, 0.8]
 [2.4, 1.6]
 [3.6, 2.9]
 [2.8, 2.5]]
```

(⚠️ *Side Note* ⚠️: If the output **does** look like five individual lists, there's probably something wrong. Perhaps the functions are *printing* lists rather than *returning* them?)

If `feat` is a list or numpy array, it can be unpacked into individual variables:

```py
import numpy as np

# list case
feat_list = [[1.4, 1.3], [0.8, 0.8], [2.4, 1.6], [3.6, 2.9], [2.8, 2.5]]
a, b, c, d, e = feat_list

# numpy array case
feat_nump = np.array([[1.4, 1.3], [0.8, 0.8], [2.4, 1.6], [3.6, 2.9], [2.8, 2.5]])
a, b, c, d, e = feat_nump
```

Any of these can be converted into DataFrames, and the result is the same:

```py
import pandas as pd

from_lists = pd.DataFrame(feat_list)
from_numpy = pd.DataFrame(feat_nump)
from_vars = pd.DataFrame([a, b, c, d, e])

print(from_lists)
print(from_numpy)
print(from_vars)
```

Output:

```
     0    1
0  1.4  1.3
1  0.8  0.8
2  2.4  1.6
3  3.6  2.9
4  2.8  2.5
     0    1
0  1.4  1.3
1  0.8  0.8
2  2.4  1.6
3  3.6  2.9
4  2.8  2.5
     0    1
0  1.4  1.3
1  0.8  0.8
2  2.4  1.6
3  3.6  2.9
4  2.8  2.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.to_csv()`:

```
import pandas as pd

a=[1.4, 1.3]
b=[0.8, 0.8]
c=[2.4, 1.6]
d=[3.6, 2.9]
e=[2.8, 2.5]
df = [a,b,c,d,e]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['column_1', 'column_2'])
print(df.to_csv(index=False))
```

Output:

```
column_1,column_2
1.4,1.3
0.8,0.8
2.4,1.6
3.6,2.9
2.8,2.5
```

Comment: Thanks Wasif. Works perfect.